# Doesn't insert csv file records in java (jdbc)

Tags: java, mysql, csv, jdbc

I have an error when my CSVLoader file does not insert the data in my database, I get this in my console

> FieldName (UploadDownloadFileServlet) = fileName
>
> FileName (UploadDownloadFileServlet) = prueba2.csv
>
> ContentType (UploadDownloadFileServlet) = application/vnd.ms-excel
>
> Size in bytes (UploadDownloadFileServlet) = 47
>
> Absolute Path at server (UploadDownloadFileServlet) = C:\Users\SISTEMAS\workspaceEclipse.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\SAC-sin-impresion\uploadedCsvFiles\prueba2.csv
>
> Query: INSERT INTO MATRICULA(C:UsersSISTEMASworkspaceEclipse.metadata.pluginsorg.eclipse.wst.server.coretmp0wtpwebappsSAC-sin-impresionuploadedCsvFilesprueba2.csv) VALUES(?)
>
> [CSVLoader]: 0 records loaded into MATRICULA DB table

THIS IS MY CODE:

```
public void loadCSV(InputStream csvFile, String tableName,
            boolean truncateBeforeLoad) throws Exception {

        CSVReader csvReader = null;
        if(null == this.connection) {
            throw new Exception("Not a valid connection.");
        }
        try {

            /* Modified by rammar.
             * 
             * I was having issues with the CSVReader using the "\" to escape characters.
             * A MySQL CSV file contains quote-enclosed fields and non-quote-enclosed NULL
             * values written as "\N". The CSVReader was removing the "\". To detect "\N"
             * I must remove the escape character, and the only character you can replace
             * it with that you are pretty much guaranteed will not be used to escape
             * text is '\0'.
             * I read this on:
             * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008395/opencsv-in-java-ignores-backslash-in-a-field-value
             * based on:
             * http://sourceforge.net/p/opencsv/support-requests/5/
             */
            // PREVIOUS VERSION: csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFile), this.seprator);
            csvReader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(csvFile), this.seprator, '"', '\0');

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new Exception("Error occured while executing file. "
                    + e.getMessage());
        }

        String[] headerRow = csvReader.readNext();

        if (null == headerRow) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException(
                    "No columns defined in given CSV file." +
                    "Please check the CSV file format.");
        }

        String questionmarks = StringUtils.repeat("?,", headerRow.length);
        questionmarks = (String) questionmarks.subSequence(0, questionmarks
                .length() - 1);


        /* NOTE from Ron: Header column names must match SQL table fields */
        String query = SQL_INSERT.replaceFirst(TABLE_REGEX, tableName);
        query = query
                .replaceFirst(KEYS_REGEX, StringUtils.join(headerRow, ","));
        query = query.replaceFirst(VALUES_REGEX, questionmarks);

        System.out.println("Query: " + query); // Modified by rammar to suppress output

        String[] nextLine;
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        try {
            con = this.connection;
            con.setAutoCommit(false);
            ps = con.prepareStatement(query);

            if(truncateBeforeLoad) {
                //delete data from table before loading csv
                con.createStatement().execute("DELETE FROM " + tableName);
            }

            final int batchSize = 1000;
            int count = 0;
            Date date = null;
            while ((nextLine = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {

                if (null != nextLine) {
                    int index = 1;
                    for (String string : nextLine) {
                        date = DateUtil.convertToDate(string);
                        if (null != date) {
                            ps.setDate(index++, new java.sql.Date(date
                                    .getTime()));
                        } else {

                            /* Section modified by rammar to allow NULL values 
                             * to be input into the DB. */
                            if (string.length() > 0 && !string.equals("\\N")) {                             
                                ps.setString(index++, string);
                            } else {
                                ps.setNull(index++, Types.VARCHAR);
                                //ps.setString(index++, null); // can use this syntax also - not sure which is better
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    ps.addBatch();
                }
                if (++count % batchSize == 0) {
                    ps.executeBatch(); 
                }
            }
            ps.executeBatch(); // insert remaining records
            System.out.println("[" + this.getClass().getSimpleName() + "]: " + 
                count + " records loaded into " + tableName + " DB table");

            con.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            con.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new Exception(
                    "Error occured while loading data from file to database."
                            + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            /*if (null != ps)
                ps.close();
                */
            /*if (null != con)
                con.close();*/

            csvReader.close();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Look at your query: `UsersSISTEMASworkspaceEclipse` - notice something is missing?

Comment: Also, it would help to post the values of SQL_INSERT, TABLE_REGEX, KEYS_REGEX and VALUES_REGEX. The part that goes wrong in your code is building the query...